# In Python 3.6+ what is the f-string to print float 9.9 as string 09.90 and 10 as 10.00?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string, zero-padding

Having looked at three other formatting questions here with tens of answers each, I don't see anyone telling how to print a float `9.9` as `09.90` and `10` as `10.00` using the same f-string:

```
x = 9.9
print(f"{x:02.2f}")  # Should print 09.90

x = 10
print(f"{x:02.2f}")  # Should print 10.00
```

The question is what should replace `:02.2f` above?

Comment: Does it matter what happens with negative numbers?  Do you want `-9.90` or `-09.90`?  Or will you simply never have negative numbers?

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't matter. This is used for a timer so once it runs out, it will be 00.00.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for

```
print(f"{x:05.2f}")
```

The number before the radix point is the *total* number of characters in the field, not the number to appear before the radix point.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=string%20format#formatspec)

Comment: Thanks! That explains it.

Answer (score 6):

```
f'{x:.2f}'
```

will print x to two decimal places.

```
f'{x:05.2f}'
```

will print x to two decimal places, with five total characters (including the decimal point)